# Where in (or near) Chicago airport can I get a few hours of sleep?

Tags: airports, sleeping, british-airways, ord

I'm flying from LAX at 5am, and have a six hour layover in ORD (O'Hare, Chicago).

I am flying business to Heathrow on British Airways.

Where can I get a few hours of sleep?

Answer (score 4):

Hilton Chicago O'Hare offers [day rooms](http://hiltonglobalmediacenter.com/index.cfm/news/hilton-chicago-ohare-airport-introduces-day-use-rooms-to-accommodate-travelers-going-through-worlds-busiest-airport):

> Available for $79 on weekends and $99 on weekdays, the Day Room
>   Package is available from 9:00 a.m.  to 6:00 p.m

The hotel is connected directly to the terminal:

> The award-winning Hilton Chicago O'Hare Airport is the only hotel
>   situated on the airport's property. There is no need to take a cab or
>   a shuttle bus since the hotel is connected to the airport terminals by
>   underground pedways